# How to drop a clustered columnstore index?

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

How can I drop a clustered columnstore index on a table?

I am trying to alter the length of a column, but getting this error:

> The statement failed because a secondary dictionary reached the maximum size limit.
> Consider dropping the columnstore index, altering the column, then creating a new columnstore index.

I have a table that looks like this, roughly:

```
CREATE TABLE [dim].[Ticket]
( 
    [ID] [bigint]  NULL,
    [Rev] [int]  NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime2](7)  NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](260)  NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](4005)  NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [ID] ),
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
```

When I try variations of this recommendation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

I just get errors.

Comment: What's the name of the columnstore index?

Comment: There is no name, apparently. That is the create table statement generated by SQL.

Comment: When you don't explicitly name the constraint / index, a name is auto-generated. You need the name to be able to drop the index. See if you can find the index name either in whatever UI you use for Synapse or by querying the [`sys.indexes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) system view, filtering the `object_id` column on the `OBJECT_ID('dim.Ticket')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked that this works on Synapse too.  Discover the CCI's name with

`select * from sys.indexes where object_id = object_id('dim.Ticket')`

then drop it

`drop index ClusteredIndex_fdddc3c574214a2096190cbc54f58cc4 on dim. Ticket`

You'll then have a heap.  When you're ready re-compress the table with

`create clustered columnstore index cci_dim_ticket on dim.Ticket`

But it would be more efficient to create a new table with a [CTAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7), and then rename and drop the old one.  Dropping the CCI actually requires rewriting the table as an uncompressed heap, which you can skip with CTAS.