# Change Clustered Columnstore Index Tables to Heap for small Tables on dedicated SQL Pool

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Clustered Columnstore Index is the default behavior while creating Tables on Azure dedicated SQL pool.
There are a number of small Tables that we use, where CCI is not beneficial,
We want to Alter the Table definition and make these tables as Heap.

What is the way that we can change the Table definition for these existing tables?
Can it be done through a simple Alter Statment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop a clustered columnstore index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74921552/how-to-drop-a-clustered-columnstore-index)

Comment: @Stu, Is there any similar way to change the Distribution as well from RR to Hash?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is In Azure Synapse Analytics, tables are stored as distributed and organized sets of data called distributions.

Instead of creating or altering a heap or clustered index, you can control the distribution and sorting of the data by using distribution keys and sorting keys when creating tables.

To change the table definition in Azure Synapse Analytics, you need to recreate the table with the desired distribution and sorting options.

For example as you said you will need no CCI Clustred Column Index for the small Tables.
Here I have created 2 sample tables with Clustered Columnstore Index.
In the synapse dedicated Pool.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers_OG
(
    CustomerID INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    Email VARCHAR(100)
)
GO
DROP INDEX ClusteredIndex_fc5016e5e92a49d8965713684ba3800c ON Customers_OG;
--Drop table Customers
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCI_Customers ON Customers_OG
GO
Select * from customers_OG
select * from orders_OG

CREATE TABLE Orders_OG
(
    OrderID INT,
    CustomerID INT,
    ProductID INT,
    Quantity INT,
    OrderDate DATE
)

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCI_Orders ON Orders_OG
--DROP INDEX ClusteredIndex_17a0349ca366487086f2a570d7312ff5 ON Orders_OG
GO
```

[image]
[image]
These above tables are built with clustred Column Index

Now in Synapse dedicated sql Pool Take the back up of the Orginal tables
Using the

```
Select * into customers_OG_bkp from customers_OG
Select * into orders_OG_bkp from orders_OG
```

[image]

[image]
Now as you have the Back up tables ready.

```
-- Drop the original Table
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Customers_OG', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.Customers_OG;


-- Recreate the table again
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers
(
    CustomerID INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    Email VARCHAR(100)
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN 
);
```

[image]

The above code will drop the Original table and Recreates the table with required schema and distributes the using the round robin method.

Same way for the orders table too.

```
-- Drop the original Table
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Orders_Og', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.Orders_Og;


-- Recreate the table again
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    OrderID INT,
    CustomerID INT,
    ProductID INT,
    Quantity INT,
    OrderDate DATE
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN 
);
```

[image]

Now you have the Tables are created Lets use the Back up tables to insert the data into the newly created tables.

Copy data from the existing back up table which have CCI. to the new table.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Customers (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Email)
SELECT CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Email
FROM dbo.Customers_OG_bkp;

INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (OrderID, CustomerID, ProductID, Quantity, OrderDate)
SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, ProductID, Quantity, OrderDate
FROM dbo.Orders_OG_Bkp
```

;
[image]

[image]

[image]